# removing whitespace from my string

Tags: java, regex, nsxmlparser

This is my string.. how can i remove the  spaces using reg exp in java

```
 08h03         Data1                Data2       Data3        Data4           5
```

Is there any way i already tried replace("    ","");

Comment: What is your expected output? Your code returns `"08h03Data1Data2Data3Data45"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably didn't reassign the string. Try:

```
String s = "08h03         Data1                Data2       Data3        Data4           5";   
s = s.replace(" ", "");
```

Note that `String.replace(...)` does not take a regex string as parameter: just a plain string.

This will remove all spaces from your string, which is an odd requirement, if you ask me. Perhaps you want to split the input? This can be done like this:

```
String[] tokens = s.split("\\s+"); // `\\s+` matches one or more white space characters
// tokens == ["08h03", "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "5"]
```

or maybe even replace 2 or more spaces with a single one? This can be done like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "); // `\\s{2,}` matches two or more white space characters
// s == "08h03 Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use replaceAll() Method.

```
String s = "08h03            Data1                Data2       Data3        Data4           5   ";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Comment: The only benefit is that it also removes tabs and newlines, if that is required. That's also the main disadvantage, if it isn't required. The key word here is *required* - it is very unclear what the OP (Original Poster) wants.

Comment: Because repalce it deals with String constant, where as replaceAll() deals with regular Expression.(all special characters in string)